# Why does my move() method not keep the ball in bounds?

Tags: java, swing, game-physics, paintcomponent, thread-sleep

**Question:** So I have created a program with a Window class that creates a JFrame and adds a JPanel from my DrawStuff class onto it. The DrawStuff class creates a ball that (is supposed to) bounce around the screen and when it hits the JFrame boundaries, change direction. The ball moves but for some reason the checkbounds part of my move method does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to keep the ball in bounds.

**Code from DrawStuff class**:

```
public class Drawstuff extends JPanel {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int dx, dy=0;

    public  Drawstuff(){
        x = 300;
        y = 250;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(x,y,50,50);    
    }
    public void move(){

        if (x < 600){
            dx = 1;
        }
        if (y < 500){
            dy = 1; 
        }
        if (x > 600){
            dx = -1; 
        }
        if (y >500){
            dy = -1;
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

}
```

**Simple "GameLoop" from Window Class (if needed)**

```
 while (true){
            stuff.repaint();
            stuff.move();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what does it do currently? Sorry just read that again my bad

Comment: `if (x < 600){}`???  Don't you mean `if (x < 0)`?  Same with "y"...

Comment: If x == 600 you just don't move?

Comment: Right now, it just moves diagonally towards the bottom right of the JFrame. @KyleT

Comment: @FoggyDay Thank you, that makes much more sense. However for some reason, now the circle remains at the center of the screen and doesn't move at all.. All I did was change those two if statements

Comment: The ball won't move if you don't tell it to. @FoggyDay's adjustment keeps the ball in play by not moving it at all. You need to keep track of the `dx` and `dy` from the last tick and use them again unless the ball hits a wall. Then give it some initial speed and you're set (for now).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `move` is wrong. The logic of it is false. You want the ball to bounce so make its movement reverse when it hits a wall. What you've done is : if it is outside get it inside and when inside try to get it outside! Change to:

```
   public void move(){
        if (x < 0) { // left bound
            dx = 1;  // now move right
        }
        if (y < 0){  // upper bound
            dy = 1;  // now move down
        }
        if (x > 600){// right bound
            dx = -1; // now move left
        }
        if (y >500){ // lower bound
            dy = -1; // now move up
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
```

For future use, I can suggest you to do it the following way :

```
   public void move(){
        if (x < 0) {   // left bound
            dx = -dx;  // now move right, same speed
            x=-x;      // bounce inside
        }
        if (y < 0){    // upper bound
            dy = -dy;  // now move down, same speed
            y=-y;      // bounce inside
        }
        if (x > 600){      // right bound
            dx = -dy;      // now move left, same speed
            x=600-(x-600); // bounce inside
        }
        if (y >500){       // lower bound
            dy = -dy;      // now move up, same speed
            y=500-(y-500); // bounce inside
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
```

So you can now use any vector speed you want (at least reasonable ones). Vector coordinates are reversed accordingly to the hit, and the ball is relocated inside the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However after one of the users pointed out my incorrect logic, I changed it to what you have above. For some reason now my circle does not move at all? @Jean-Baptiste

Comment: not only pixels coordinates, e.g. - 1.Thread.sleep(5); is under Latency for standard Native OS'es, standard minimal value should be 25-33, 2. invoked from Swing Timer for Java6 and newer versions, because Thread.sleep(int); block an EDT, more in Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing

Comment: @mKorbel I am not sure if I understood everything you said, but if it helps, the circle moved at a decent speed with the move logic in my posted move method. Then I just changed two if statement logics suggested by "foggy day" and now my circle does not move at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should give it an initial movement! Set dx=1, dy=1 for example... @imgolden62

Comment: Don't know who downvoted it, but that's an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that I initialized dx and dy to 0 in the constructor… :0 @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: Yes the speed is too fast, but this is not the problem at the moment. And there is no problem with EDT blocking here, except if the while loop is located in some event listener. Is this the case ?